# Using composer and its json file, how can I set package specific URLS?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php

I'm trying to install Bootstrap and jQuery via composer, and I managed to install jQuery in   `public/js/vendor` but now I want to add Twitter Bootstrap as well but have it under `public/css/vendor`. My composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "2.1.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "v3.1.*" // Where do I specify the install dir for this?
    },
    "component-dir": "public/js/vendor"
}
```

So I want Bootstrap to end up under `public/css/vendors.` How can I set package specific urls and not one for everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`components/bootstrap`](https://github.com/components/bootstrap) package instead.

But it's way better to use Composer only for PHP packages. Use [Bower](http://bower.io/) for front-end packages (like jQuery and bootstrap).